# Вызов события для control-а на другой вкладке приводит к исключению

Tags: wpf, usercontrol, controls

Есть элемент управления, который имеет анимацию DoubleAnimationUsingPath, анимация запускается по событию RoutedEvent="ui:CheckBoxProgressCircle.Check"

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ui:CheckBoxProgressCircle.Check">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>

                <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                              PathGeometry="{StaticResource CheckAnimationPath}"
                                              Source="X"
                                              Duration="0:0:.1" />

            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

В коде регистрирую событие:

```
static CheckBoxProgressCircle()
{
    CheckEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Check", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CheckBoxProgressCircle));
}

public event RoutedEventHandler Check
{
    add
    {
        AddHandler(CheckEvent, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        RemoveHandler(CheckEvent, value);
    }
}
```

Далее вызываю событие:

```
var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(CheckEvent);
RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
```

Если элемент управления находится на вкладке, которая активна, все работает без ошибок, если элемент управления находится на вкладке, которая ни разу активной не становилась, получаю ошибку:

> ''AnimatedTranslateTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.'

Я думаю, это из за того, что элемент управления не отрисовался wpf, т.к. был на неактивной вкладке и не имеет AnimatedTranslateTransform, как можно принудительно заставить wpf отрисовать этот элемент? Или если я не прав, что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Решение оказалось давольно простым: можно вызвать метод ApplyTemplate(); для этого элемента управления. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение оказалось давольно простым: можно вызвать метод ApplyTemplate(); для этого элемента управления. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx